# Amazon Cognito and LinkedIn Learning xAPI - scope issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, access-token, awscognitotoken

I am trying to get oauth authorization for LinkedIn Learning xAPI webhooks.

According to their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/learning/integrations/xapi#authentication), they will send an authorization request and require an access token to be sent back.

Basically they are going to hit an endpoint with the following parameters:

- grant_type : client_credentials
- scope: xapi:write
- client_id: {{ supplied client_id }}
- client_secret: {{ supplied client_secret }}

I have set up Amazon Cognito to handle this, but one small problem is that when you set up a scope with Amazon Cognito, they force you to also add a scope identifier (a URL). This then makes the scope look something like this:

`http://your-domain.com/xapi:write`

I have tried in Postman to use just xapi:write as the LinkedIn Learning xAPI docs say, but that triggers an invalid_scope error and does not allow me to get an access token.

Is there any way around this? If not I may need to find another solution for getting an access token.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use a [Microsoft Authorization Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?tabs=HTTPS) to access those resources. That is how it works - you use the data owner's system to get a token - and your own AWS Cognito system will not work.